# Route does not find variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i need to pass a variable `$empresa`  to my route, but it can't find it.

find the route only as ( / )

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else {
    
        $empresa = Auth::user()->empresa;
                    return redirect('/' .$empresa);
    }    
});
```

I only get this problem in `web.php` file
help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That' likely because you haven't declared a controller for the route `/` with parameter.

It's not always a best practice to declare a controller right in route file like this. But let's ignore that and continue.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
    else {

      $empresa = Auth::user()->empresa;
                return redirect('/')->with(['empress' => $empresa]);
    }
});
```

Just make sure that you have declared a controller for `/{empress}` route. Something like this:

```
Route::get('/{empress}', 'YourController@methodName');
```